# linear Analysis (Continuous at a point)

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm checking to see if a function is continuous.

$f(z)=\frac{Re(z^2)}{|z|^2}$ if z $\neq 0$,-1 if z=0

I let $x=\alpha t$
,$y=\beta t$

and I ended up with  lim_t->0$\frac{t^2(\alpha^4 +2\alpha^2 \beta^2 + \beta^4)}{\alpha^2 - \beta^2}$.

Im concluding that this isn't continuous as it depends on the path we take for eg when $\alpha^2 = \beta^2$ this limit does not exist and when $\alpha^2 \neq \beta^2$ we get  the limit to be 0. I was just wondering is my conclusion correct

Comment: Please give the entire problem. As it is you havent even mentioned what f is.

Comment: Actually you do. For example, is $0$ even in the domain of your function? $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous, but is ill defined at $0$.

Comment: It should have been mentioned in the problem about alpha and beta, otherwisr the problem is ambiguos, because then the limit you showed will not be defined for any t. Thats a rather absurd conclusion. Thats why i suggested you upload the full problem